# Single Number II - Need a generic solution

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am trying to solve this problem [Leetcode - Single Number ii](https://leetcode.com/problems/single-number-ii/).

> Given a non-empty array of integers, every element appears three times except for one, which appears exactly once. Find that single one.
>
> Note:
>
> Your algorithm should have a linear runtime complexity. Could you implement it without using extra memory?
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: [2,2,3,2]
>   Output: 3

The solution described below is from the [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-element-that-appears-once/) and they have explained it very nicely how this problem can be solved, kudos to them.

```
static int getSingle(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
        int ones = 0, twos = 0; 
        int common_bit_mask; 

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++ ) 
        { 
            /*"one & arr[i]" gives the bits that are there in 
            both 'ones' and new element from arr[]. We 
            add these bits to 'twos' using bitwise OR*/
            twos = twos | (ones & arr[i]); 

            /*"one & arr[i]" gives the bits that are 
            there in both 'ones' and new element from arr[]. 
            We add these bits to 'twos' using bitwise OR*/
            ones = ones ^ arr[i]; 

            /* The common bits are those bits which appear third time 
            So these bits should not be there in both 'ones' and 'twos'. 
            common_bit_mask contains all these bits as 0, so that the bits can  
            be removed from 'ones' and 'twos'*/
            common_bit_mask = ~(ones & twos); 

            /*Remove common bits (the bits that appear third time) from 'ones'*/
            ones &= common_bit_mask; 

            /*Remove common bits (the bits that appear third time) from 'twos'*/
            twos &= common_bit_mask; 
        } 
        return ones; 
    }
```

But I am breaking my head how can I make this solution more generic. Let's say if a number repeats 5 times [2,2,3,2,2,2] instead of 3 times, how can I tweak this solution?

I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted and ask a question according to what you don't understand and what is not working properly.  Additionally do not depend on outside resources to ask your question as links can eventually die, transfer the information into the post.  Also "how can I tweak this solution" is not really a proper question as it is extremely open ended, and really is just asking someone to do the solution for you.

Comment: Is the solution in the Question, posted by you? If not, we would appreciate to see your attempt for the solution.

Comment: I have updated my question. Hope this helps.

Comment: `Let's say if a number repeats 5 times` The instructions say that every number repeats 3 times, so you don't need to worry about more.  You do need to worry that there's more numbers: [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,6,6,6].

Comment: My question is what would the answer if the number repeats 5 times.